# Supply an array of lists into a ACF dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress

So I'm running into some trouble and unsure how I can do this, but I'd like to supply an array of lists to an Advanced Custom Field 'Select' field, which I'm unsure how to do properly.

Here is the `form` method inside my widget class:

```
// This is the backend of the widgets
public function form($instance)
{
    $api = MailChimp_API::init();
    var_dump($api->get_lists());

    // Grab the widget ID
    $widget_id = $this->id;

    // The ACF Lists are empty at first
    $acf_lists = get_field('mailchimp_list', $widget_id) ? get_field('mailchimp_list',$widget_id) : '';
}
```

The `get_lists()` method spills out an multi-dimensional array of lists as shown below:

[image]

The `$acf_lists` variable is my get_field from the database that is not present at the moment because I don't have any details to pass to it. Here is the ACF field inside my group:

[image]

Here is the lists dropdown inside the widget:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following hook to fill the ACF dropdown field with values from get_lists. Here's a sample code.

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field ) {
    $api = MailChimp_API::init();
    $lists = $api->get_lists();

    $field['choices'] = [];
    foreach($lists as $list) {
     $field['choices'][$list['id']] = $list['name'];
    }
    return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/key=field_123abcf', 'my_acf_load_field');
```

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/

Comment: Works like a charm @Nick, thanks a bunch! I wasn't aware that you had to hook into an action.